# Simply connected does not imply contractible. Is there a nice counter example in $R^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples

The standard counter example to the claim that a simply connected space might be contractible is a sphere $S^n$, with $n > 1$, which is simply connected but not contractible. Suppose that I were interested in a counter example in the plane - does anyone know of a subset of $R^2$ which is simply connected but not contractible?

Comment: Does your definition of contractible require that the resulting point be fixed for all $t$? $\hspace{1.7 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer Does it make a difference? Either definition is fine, just be sure to explain which one you are using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consider the topologist sine curve

$$y = \sin \bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg),\  1\geq x>0$$

together with the interval $\{(0, t): |t|\leq 1\}$ and a curve joining this interval with the graph. This is simply connected but is not contractible. You may find the proof of noncontractibility in

http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math205B-2012/polishcircle.pdf

Comment: Is this path connected ? As far as I can recall it is not ... then how is it simply connected ?

Comment: Topologist sine curve is not. Polish circle *is* path connected. You couldn't reach the vertical interval from the sine curve in the first case, but you can in the latter, by going in the opposite direction ;)

Answer (score 7):

John's answer is absolutely correct, but here is an addendum to it: All proper subsets $Z$ of the plane are aspherical in the sense that every continuous map 
$$
f: S^n\to Z, n>1,
$$
extends to a continuous map of the ball, $B^{n+1}\to Z$. See the paper [One-dimensional sets and planar sets are aspherical](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101000050) by Cannon, Conner and Zastrow.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I don't see how it is an extension of John's answer. (Though I haven't yet read either of the linked papers.)

Comment: @user54092: The point is that the linked paper proves that if such a space Z is simply connected then it is weakly contractible.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about weak contractibility.

Comment: So the point is that you can't find a counter example in the plane which is a CW complex. That's good to know.