# simply connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$ contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, path-connected

I know that every simply connected open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is homeomorphic with $\mathbb R^2$ . My question is : Is every simply connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$ contractible ?

Remark : By simply connected I mean path connected with trivial fundamental group .

Comment: This may be of interest : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548681/simply-connected-does-not-imply-contractible-is-there-a-nice-counter-example-in

Comment: Why isn't the circle, $S^2$ a counterexample, as I think @Bass was hinting.

Comment: The circle (which by the way is $S^1$ not $S^2$) is not a counterexample because it is not simply connected.

Comment: @Bass : I believe that the example given in the link is not path connected and hence not simply connected , as simply connected means path connected and trivial fundamental group

Comment: @misao The example in the link (often called the Polish circle) actually is simply connected.

Comment: @mixedmath : No it is not , as it is not path connected. The definition of Simply connected includes path connected (at least as I have read from Munkres) , which the space in the linked example is not

Comment: My point is that it is path connected.

Comment: @mixedmath : How is that ? The closed sine curve is not path connected ...

Comment: That is what the additional line segment is for, which is why it's called a Polish *circle*. To go from the 'left' of the sine to the right, one instead goes around the circle.