# Are simply connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ all contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

The question see above. I thought there is a counter-example but not sure:

$A:=\{(x,\sin\frac{\pi}{x}):x\in(0,1]\}$, Then $A'=\{(0,y):y\in [-1,1]\}$. Take $\overline{A}$ and connect $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ with some arbitrary Jordan curve. It's simply connected, and I think a homotopy contracting it to a point would be impossible due to the continuousness problem at $(0,y)\times 0$ of $H(\vec{x},t)$, but I don't know how to give a strict proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By “simple connected”, do you mean “simply connected”?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simply connected does not imply contractible. Is there a nice counter example in $R^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548681/simply-connected-does-not-imply-contractible-is-there-a-nice-counter-example-in)

Comment: @LukasJuhrich yes i do, just edited the question, thank you

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, thank you!