# Non-contractible space, but all maps are homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am being asked to find a NON CONTRACTIBLE space $X$ such that, for any path-connected space $Y$ and any continuous maps $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$, $f$ and $g$ are homotopic.

I have thought that I definitely cannot pick $X$ to be path-connected, since otherwise picking $Y = X$, $f = Id_X$ and $g$ a constant map, I would obtain that $X$ is contractible. That said I am not too sure where to look for an actual example.

The classic example of a space that is not contractible but has trivial fundamental group, $S^2$, also cannot work here, since degree of maps is a homotopy invariant and clearly many different degree maps exist!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered a connected space that is not path-connected?

Comment: I have not. I guess the topologist's sine curve is the canonical example for this, but isn't it contractible?

Comment: no, it's not contractible, see, e.g., here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548681/simply-connected-does-not-imply-contractible-is-there-a-nice-counter-example-in

Comment: @Thomas That seems to refer to the *closed* topologist's sine curve or the Warsaw circle, but maybe I'm missing the spot. But isn't it clear that if we take a homotopy to the constant map (choosing the fixed point $x_0$ in the vertical line segment), the image of $\{x\}\times [0,1]$ gives a path from $x$ to $x_0$?

Comment: Hint: try some finite spaces.

Comment: @TedShifrin no you are not missing the spot, I'm doing too many things simultaneously. My apologies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. The space you are looking for is... $\{1,2\}$ or any discrete space with at least two points. Note that a contractible space has to be connected.

As for why $\{1,2\}$ satisfies your condition I leave it as an exercise.

Comment: Grrrr. ......... :D

Comment: There is an even simpler example with less than two points.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I got it now!

Comment: Grrrr$^2$ to @Moishe. That is really bad! But, as always with topological questions, someone should be the custodian of the empty set.

Comment: Just to check I am right: if I have a function $f$ from {1,2} to Y, would the correct homotopy be $H: {1,2} \times I \rightarrow Y$ which is defined by $H(1, -) = f(1)$ and $H(2, t) = p(t)$ where $p$ is the path starting at $f(2)$ and ending at $f(1)$?

This would give me homotopy between f and the constant map at f(1), and then since all constant maps are homotopic in a path connected space, I obtain homotopy between f and any other map.

Comment: @Sausage_Devourer yeah, that's one way to approach this, sure.

Comment: Thank you :) Would there be an easier way to reach this same conclusion?

Comment: @Sausage_Devourer you can do this directly: let $X$ be discrete and $Y$ path connected. Consider two functions $f,g:X\to Y$. For any $x\in X$ consider a path $\lambda_x:[0,1]\to Y$ from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$. Define homotopy $H(x,t)=\lambda_x(t)$. Check that $H$ is continuous thanks to the fact that $X$ is discrete.